# VFP font size in command window

Tags: font-size, visual-foxpro

In the VFP development environment both the command window and any code windows which are open display characters in Courier font, possible 10 pt.  I would like to reduce the size of these characters, to see more lines on the screen.

Have tried going into Tools | Options | IDE and have changed several font specifications (for Desktop, Program files, Code Windows, Procedures), clicked on 'Apply' in an attempt to reduce the size of these character on the screen.  This has not been successful.

How can I reduce the font size used for code when I am editing it, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the Override individual settings checkbox on the Options | IDE tab. Otherwise, if you've previously edited a particular PRG, you'll see the font you used then.

For the Command Window, right-click, Properties to set the font.

Comment: Thanks Tamar.  Think I am getting the hang of this.  It is indeed Tools | Options | IDE settings.  In my case it is then 'Type = Code Windows', check 'Over-ride individual'.  What threw me is that it does not apply to currently open code-windows, but it does apply to all subsequently opened windows.

Comment: And that worked for me, too.  Thanks.  I never noticed the 'Override' button back when I was looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, I use the default, but occasionally I change it by right-clicking within the MODIFY COMMAND window I'm working in, going into "Properties...", and changing the font size.  It only applies when editing that filename, though.  Many years ago I think I tried changing it globally, as you seem to have, and remember it not 'sticking', so henceforth I always changed it on a file-by-file basis when I needed to.

Comment: Thanks LAK;  that certainly changes the font size in the command window, or as you say, an individual code window in that session.  I'll keep looking for a permanent fix, so that on each new VFP session I am in 9 point.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is under Tools / Options / EDITOR tab, and save whatever defaults you want and set as Default.

Additionally, another thing I have done this in the past and created my own master settings resource file.  By default when you start VFP, a "resource" file is set to ex: C:\Program Files\VFP\blah\FoxUser.dbf  (and the corresponding .fpt file)

What I would do is this.  Use the resource file and make an EMPTY copy of it to a new location, such as the working folder of your project.

```
use ( sys(2005)) again alias tmpResource 
copy structure to MyVFPResource
set resource to MyVFPResource
close tables all
```

The resource file keeps track of almost every thing you open / work with and retains settings such as window area, position, etc.  Some things I like to have as a "default", such as when editing snippet methods in screen or class designer.  Such as to always have the row/column of a file displayed, have other settings.

An example of common .prg files.  Do a simple MODI COMM MyTest.prg.  Then once a simple .prg file is open, go to Edit, then Properties.  Click on all the settings you want (including font size, line/column, syntax coloring, tabs vs space preferences, etc.  Click the checkbox for "Apply to .PRG files". and click ok.

Now, open your resource file AGAIN so you can see what is stored.

```
use ( sys(2005)) again alias tmpResource 
BROWSE
```

You will see many rows, but at the bottom will be the most recent entries.  You should see 3 records listed as "WINDMODIFY" which represents the "MODIFY COMMAND" of whatever prg file.  Now, open the "Name" memo field.  One will be listed as .prg, another will be "DEFAULT", and the last will be the actual "mytest.prg" you started with.  Get on the "DEFAULT" version record.  Now you can change the "READONLY" column from FALSE to TRUE (F/T) and it will lock these settings for ALL .prg files.  You can then delete the other rows.

You can apply these same principles to modifying form code snippets.  Open a form, double-click on any method, then EDIT / Properties, do the same, but checkbox for "Apply to method code".

Browse the resource file and look at the "WINDSNIP" rows.  Again, look for "DEFAULT" and mark that readonly as .T. and you can delete the other.  The resource file will literally save every snippet window specific to the form, object, method, etc.

Do the same for visual class file editing too.

Similarly can be done for toolbars and more as you browse and see.  When you are done making all the changes you want, purge out all the other fluff, close the resource file and set it to read-only so no additional garbage gets pulled into it.

If you need to change in the future, make the table editable again, make changes, then readonly the table again.

Then, all you have to do is at VFP start, do

```
set resource to MyVFPResource
```

Comment: Thanks DRApp.  However, in the matter of the 'Tools / Options / EDITOR' tab, I do not see an option the change the font-size. There is a 'Font style' option, but that only changes to bold / italic and can change the colour.  Is there a hidden font-size otion on that screen?

Comment: @Andrew_46, the font sizing stuff should be available based on the secondary portion of the MODI COMM and editing form / visual class snippets.  That dialog allows full font name, style and size.  Then by saving the "defaults" as described, should be applied across the board for you.

Comment: @Andrew_46, if you provide me your email, I will send you a copy of a "Resource" file that does exactly what I described and I have the .prg and code snippets at font-size Courier 6pt just to prove the point.

Comment: Yes please, if I am allowed to.  I am ckmozley and the email provider is btinternet.com